# How to retrive Image data from Image view in android

Tags: android

I have two Image view I have to compare them. I don't know on which format I have to take them.I want to retrieve Image Data.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are :)

```
imageView.getDrawable();
```

Then just compare two Drawables from both :)

Comment: Thanks a lot we can do by above method.

Answer (score 0):

**(not sure but)** i think first you need to store in `drawable` data type and and convert it in to `Blob` or `String` then you can compare

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. But I have got the answer. I have converted the Image to the Bit Map Then compared That Bitmap. Actually I am facing the problem while converting Image to Bit Map. But by using the following method we can convert Image to BitMap.                                                              BitmapDrawable mdrawable = (BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable();
 Bitmap bit1 = mdrawable.getBitmap();